# else Statement not being triggered after if(empty($var))

Tags: php

I've tried searching for a solution to my problem on stackoverflow but can't seem to find one that fits my situation.

```
<?php
if (empty($userName)){
    print <<<HERE
        <form>
            Please enter your name:
                <input type="text" name="userName">
                    <br>
                <input type="submit">
        </form>
HERE;
}
else {
    print "<h3>Hi there, $userName!</h3>";
} //end
?>
```

When I enter a value into the form field it is assigned to the variable $userName but the issue occurs when the else statement is not being triggered after that value has been added.

I hope I've been clear enough, looking forward to a possible solution.

Thank You.

Comment: most likely _"the form field is __not__ assigned to the variable $userName"_. Please show how you do that! Is that also the form submitting to this?

Comment: `$userName` isn't automaticly filled with the corresponding value from the form. Values from forms are in `$_GET` (default) or `$_POST` arrays. You need to assign them to a var: `$userName = $_GET['userName'];`

Comment: Well, unless you're using `register_globals`, but that hasn't been possible since PHP 5.4.0. Please tell me you're not working from a codebase (or following a tutorial) that's *that* old?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yup, you caught me. I've recently started learning PHP and I thought I'd start with an older version and once I've mastered that I would then update my knowledge as to how PHP has progressed since then (for example: register_globals being deprecated, the why and workaround/replacement)

I see now however that it'll just cause me more headaches then it'll actually benefit me. So I'll just start again with PHP7. Thank You and I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @Jeff actually it used to be back in the PHP4-5.4 days, check `register_globals` - it was disabled by default in php4.2.0, but was still possible to enable manually until php 5.4.0

Comment: @hanshenrik true. But that's more than 10 years ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you retrieving your value from your variable? I don't see that in your question.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userName'])) {
$userName = $_POST['userName']; //This will take the userName input and put it into a variable for you to test.
}

if (empty($userName)){
    print <<<HERE
        <form>
            Please enter your name:
                <input type="text" name="userName">
                    <br>
                <input type="submit">
        </form>
HERE;
}
else {
    print "<h3>Hi there, $userName!</h3>";
} //end
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this code only works if `register_globals` is enabled, and register_global was removed since PHP 5.4.0, so this code won't work in PHP 5.4+, nor will it work if `register_globals` is disabled in PHP.ini (and it has been disabled-by-default since PHP 4.2.0), try

```
if (empty($_GET['userName'])){
```

instead. also, seems you're wide open to XSS here, the variable needs to be escaped before being echoed back to the user, or you open your website to xss attacks by hackers.

try

```
function hhb_tohtml(string $str):string
{
    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
}
    print "<h3>Hi there, ".hhb_tohtml($_GET['userName'])."!</h3>";
```